# Multiple Search Queries from one page to different content sources

Tags: search, content

I am designing a search page that needs to have 3 search boxes - each querying a different content source.

How do I link each of these to display search results from each of these 3 different content sources?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what you described I think you should use Content Search Web Part. It enables you to specify query (result source).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679900(v=office.15).aspx